# How can I remove vibration when the phone is turned off on my Samsung Galaxy S9 (non-rooted Android 9, One UI 1.0)?

Tags: 9.0-pie, vibration, samsung-galaxy-s-9

How can I remove vibration when the phone is turned off on my Samsung Galaxy S9 (non-rooted Android 9, One UI 1.0)?

I don't have any option item `Settings app > Accessibility > Vibration`.

Comment: I don't understand this part "when the phone is turned off". If it is off, how will you change any setting?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I meant: when I turn off the phone, it vibrates right when the shut down is complete. I can change settings when the phone is on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is option is not for user’s control. It’s default for all smartphones.

The main purpose is to alert the user when their phone shuts down otherwise there is a chance that users may not know whether their phone is off or on.

So OEM provides this feature as default and cannot be controlled until the phone is rooted. Rooting a phone will give you a full control over the phone. But this is helpful. If you feel to remove this option, root your device but that is difficult fix to this. Mainly it is not a bug.

Hope it helps!